# Subscript out of range, what am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have an Excel Macro that I'm trying to run on every sheet in the workbook. It's just to set up print areas and page breaks, but there are 460 sheets to do. They are all in exactly the same format so it should be straight forward. I'm using the worksheet codenames so that shouldn't be an issue.

The macro works on the active sheet then the error comes when it tries to loop to the next sheet.

Sheets("sheet" + LTrim(Str(i + 1)) + "").Select is the line it's debugging on. Please see the whole code below. I have a feeling this is a pretty simple wood for the trees moment, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Sub setup()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 460

ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A64")
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$3"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = "&A"
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 46
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

Sheets("sheet" + LTrim(Str(i + 1)) + "").Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing .Select with .Activate.

Comment: "I'm using the worksheet codenames ": No, you don't. In `Sheets("Sheet1")` the name "Sheet1" is not the codename but the real name of the sheet.

Comment: Why not use `For Each wrkSht in ThisWorkBook.Worksheets` (with `Dim wrkSht as WorkSheet`)... `Next wrkSht`.  You'll need to replace each instance of `ActiveWorksheet` with `wrkSht`.

Comment: DoctorMick - thanks but it didn't resolve it

Comment: Axel Richter - Thanks for the comment. So how should I change it to be using the codenames correctly?

Comment: Darren - Thanks for the suggestion. how would I implement the changes in the code? Should I be completely removing the last section of code that involves the sheet names?

Comment: I'll add as an answer as not enough room in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each worksheet is an object within the worksheets collection - and you can step through each item in a collection using a `For Each` loop.

Your original code looks like it was recorded and updated (nothing wrong with that).  The macro recorder records everything though - including settings that are default settings (so you don't need to specify their value - only if you want it different from the default).
Lines such as `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24` can be removed as that's just your mouse click to scroll down the screen a bit.

```
Public Sub SetUp()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    'Look at each wrksht in turn.
    'If you want to ignore certain worksheets you could use a
    'SELECT CASE statement within the loop.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wrkSht
            'Remove all manually added page breaks.
            'Resets to automatic page breaks.
            'Microsoft Help helpfully just says:
            'Resets all page breaks on the specified worksheet (thanks for that MS).
            .ResetAllPageBreaks
            .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Range("A64")
            With .PageSetup
                'You can ignore settings that are set as default.
                'Not sure what they all are, but probably include anything that ends in =""
                'for a start.
                .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$3"
                .CenterHeader = "&A"
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
                .PrintHeadings = False
                .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
                .PrintQuality = 600
                .Orientation = xlLandscape
                .Zoom = 46
            End With
        End With
    Next wrkSht

    Application.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the repaired code, and the extra information on the macro recording. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Order your Excel sheets by position and you can use:

```
Sheets(i + 1).Select
```

instead of :

```
Sheets ( "sheet" + LTrim (Str (i + 1)) + "").Select
```

Example Sheets (1) may be the first in position. Sheets (2) is the second, and so on ... All your sheets will be marked by their positions. But be careful not to create / delete sheets.
Hope this can help!